# Is it possible to return true if toast is show

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

If I need to check is toast is display I use this:

```
viewWithTextResId(server_error).inRoot(ToastMatcher())
                .checkDisplayed()

fun ViewInteraction.checkDisplayed(): ViewInteraction {
    return check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}

class ToastMatcher : TypeSafeMatcher<Root>() {

    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("is toast")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(root: Root): Boolean {
        val type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type
        if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST) {
            val windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken()
            val appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken()
            if (windowToken === appToken) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Nice it's work fine.
But I need test that return boolean if toast is show/hide.